# How to insert element before text of an element using the text node as an indication to insert the <a> element just before it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this DOM structure (I can't alter the elements(add id,class etc) only add elements)

```
<td>
    <div></div>
    613-5557896
</td>
```

I need to insert `<a>` element before the text.
So my final structure will look like this

```
<td>
    <div></div>
    <a id="111" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
    613-5557896
</td>
```

In addition this is a generic function and sometimes the div element is not present at all. 
**I can't guarantee the order.**
I can't guarantee the structure- the div might not be there or there might be more elements in the  after the text node.
I need to grab on a text node and insert the  element **just before it**.
Probably I need a correct selector to select the text node.

Comment: No duplicate, I need to use the text node as an anchor.

Comment: In the dupe, just like in your question, an element needs to be inserted before a text node. In both cases, the solution is to navigate to the text node and use insert before. it's a dupe.

Comment: This is not a duplicate since I can't guarantee the order - can't use first child last child etc

Comment: That is a separate problem entirely, unrelated to inserting an element before another.

Comment: True I specified the element type in the question

Comment: Note that your question is a bit ambiguous... `anchor` means `<a></a>`. but i don't think that's what you meant when you said "using the text node as an anchor". To me that's asking to convert a text node to an anchor element, but your question seems to be asking how to put an anchor element before a text node.

Comment: @KevinB I edited the question, please remove the duplication

Comment: I still believe it is a dupe. Anyone else with enough rep can reverse it if they fill differently. The answer is still `parentDiv.insertBefore(theAnchorNode, theTextNode)`

Comment: HOW is this a dup? This is a different situation. FACT- the answer for the other post will not work for me and the answer of @Mohammad is working

Comment: parentDiv.insertBefore(theAnchorNode, theTextNode) – @KevinB how do you grab on theTextNode?

Comment: that's a separate question. You can do so by iterating over the childnodes till you find the one you want. https://jsfiddle.net/wmb8y8sy/1/ You haven't specified what makes that text node any different from any other text node on your page.

Comment: I used lastChild as an example, but that won't work for you either because you can't guaentee that it's first, last, 3rd, 5th, or anything. you can't just say "grab the text node" and expect it to grab the one you want out of many. If there's only one, then iterating over the child nodes and filtering by nodetype would work. but again, that's a separate question that is also a duplicate.

Comment: @Kevin B - That's the problem - I need a selector to grab on my text node. Run it in the debugger tool and you will see. Or if you don't want to handle it - remove the duplication and let other people answer it.

Comment: Then ask that instead, in a separate question so i can close it as a dupe too. Or you can use the search functionality.

Comment: @KevinB - Thank you for keeping our stackoverflow community clean from duplicated questions!!! Great job!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery [`.contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) return childrens of element. Use it to getting childs of `td` and use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter selected childs to selecting only target text. At the end use [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) to insert HTML after selected text.

```
$("td").contents().filter(function(i, ele){
  return ele.nodeType == 3 && ele.nodeValue.trim() != "";  
}).before('<a id="111" href="javascript:void(0)">link</a>');
```

```js
$("td").contents().filter(function(i, ele){
  return ele.nodeType == 3 && ele.nodeValue.trim() != "";  
}).before('<a id="111" href="javascript:void(0)">link</a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div></div>
      613-5557896
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

So if you have multiple text in element, and you want to insert anchor only before first text, use [`.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) to selecting first text from set of selector.

```
$("td").contents().filter(function(i, ele){
    return ele.nodeType == 3 && ele.nodeValue.trim() != "";  
}).first().before('<a id="111" href="javascript:void(0)">link</a>');
```

```js
$("td").contents().filter(function(i, ele){
 return ele.nodeType == 3 && ele.nodeValue.trim() != "";  
}).first().before('<a id="111" href="javascript:void(0)">link</a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div></div>
      613-5557896
      <div></div>
      613-5557896
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use JQuery `after` (http://api.jquery.com/after/)

JS

```
$('.appendTo').after('<a id="111" href="javascript:void(0)">');
```

HTML (before):

```
 <td>
    <div class='appendTo'></div>
    613-5557896
 </td>
```

HTML (after):

```
 <td>
    <div class='appendTo'></div>
    <a id="111" href="javascript:void(0)">
    613-5557896
 </td>
```

Comment: I can't alter the HTML before so I can't add anything to a div element. The div element is empty

Comment: @PolinaF. What about `$('td > div').after(...`?

Comment: The div is not always there so can't use it

Answer (score -1):

If you need text nodes, use the `.lastChild` property in vanilla JavaScript as the reference. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/lastChild)

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = "javascript:void(0)";
td.insertBefore(a, td.lastChild);
```

This is assuming `td` is your `<td>` element selected by JavaScript in someway.

Comment: I can't guarantee the order. What if after the text node there will be another element. I need to grab the text node and stick<a> element before the node

Comment: Will you know what the text is?